# Git change source of new branch to older commit of source branch

Tags: git, github

I have a branch mainline with commit history 1->2->3->4->5. I have created a local branch test from mainline using

```
git checkout -b "test"
```

I made some commits into test branch say 6->7.

This is mapped from head of mainline which is commit no 5 (i.e 5->6->7).

I want the test branch to map head of mainline from commit no 1. (i.e 1->6->7)

How to do this ?

Comment: Do you want to remove the commit 2->3->4->5 from the test branch ?

Comment: Yes..I dont want commits 2->3->4->5 in test branch..

Comment: Then you would rebase 6-7 (your branch) on top of 1.

Comment: Yes @LasseV.Karlsen

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rebase --onto` to do that.

```
>>> git checkout test
>>> git checkout -b test2  # [optional] in case you have already pushed the test branch to remote, you can use test2 branch instead
>>> git rebase --onto <commit_id_of_1> <commit_id_of_5> <commit_id_of_7>
```

Example:-

```
>>> git checkout test
>>> git log --oneline
c05a4af  commit 7
b0e5f24  commit 6
74c9673  commit 5
...
6712bec  commit 1

>>> git rebase --onto 6712be 74c9673 c05a4af
```

[rebase documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

Comment: Although this will help you if you already pushed to the remote by now I suggest you not to do rebase.

Comment: He can create a new branch in that case, not that big of an issue

Comment: I did a rebase and it created a new branch (HEAD detached from 8904539).

Comment: How to pull it in my test branch

Comment: On which branch you rebased?

Comment: I rebased on test branch

Comment: git branch
* (HEAD detached from 8904539)
  mainline
  test

Comment: I am guessing rebase probably caused some conflict, that you need to fix. run `git status` to verify.

Answer (score 1):

Using Cherry Pick

```
git checkout commit_id_7
git checkout -b repair new_test_branch
git cherry-pick commit_id_6
git cherry-pick commit_id_1
git checkout test
git reset --hard commit_id_7
git merge repair
git push --hard origin test
```

**Note :Git rebase & cherrypick are dangerous but powerful solutions that should only be used as a last option**

Comment: I wouldn't say it should only be used as a last option, but should definitely be used with caution, since they alter the branches' history. But as long as you know what you're doing and do not alter *public* history, `rebase` and `cherry-pick` are perfectly fine to use.

Comment: @kowsky: completely Agree, but prevention is better than cure :P